# How to reposition things in a CCS media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have a navigation menu that is responsive using css media queries. When the nav is in desktop/laptop view the whole menu works fine. The nav tags are placed under an image in laptop desktop view which is how I want it but When it is in mobile view I need the nav tags and everything inside it to be placed about an img. I already have a css media query setup with some other styles in it but I think I need a javascript to do what I want.

Hope someone can help,

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a code snippet or [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) of what you have so far?

Comment: The result doesn't look right but it shows you the code I have

Comment: Do you have the link to the JS Fiddle?

Comment: Oh yea sorry      https://jsfiddle.net/d26g0785/

Comment: So, in mobile view, where do you want the red menu?

Comment: Thankyou but samuli's answer worked for me

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the media queries that I used for your question,

```
#mobileImg{
    display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    #desktopImg{
        display:none;
    }
    #mobileImg{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Here is the [**working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/48q104qs/)

So to explain what I did, I have two images one with the id `desktopImg` and other as `mobileImg`. The `desktopImg` is above the `nav` tags and `mobileImg` is below the `nav` tags. Using the media queries, I'm setting the `display` of `mobileImg` as `none` for desktops/laptops. Similarly for mobile view, I made the `mobileImg` visible and the `desktopImg` invisible by making its `display` as `none`